# Is this correct? $(\sum_{m<|j| <n} a_j)^2 = \sum_{m<|j| <n}\sum_{m<|k| <n} a_j a_k$

Tags: calculus

Let $ (a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} $ a sequence and $n>m$.
Is this correct?

$$ \left(\sum_{m<|j| <n} a_j \right)^2 = \sum_{m<|j| <n}\sum_{m<|k| <n} a_j a_k$$

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: How to prove this?